# How to write Lambda properties in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have not coded in VB.NET for about 10 years and now I'm having trouble finding the equivalent syntax for this:

```
public virtual string SomeProperty => "SomeValue";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB does not have the expression-bodied members. You have to do it the traditional way:

```
Public Overridable ReadOnly Property SomeProperty() As String
    Get
        Return "SomeValue"
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't identical in the general case, but for this specific case, you could use an implicitly-defined property with initialization:

```
Public Overridable ReadOnly Property SomeProperty As String = "SomeValue"
```

This is less general than the C# above in that it only works for an initial value, whereas I believe the C# can define a function which would be evaluated each time the property value is retrieved.  (In this case, the C# function just returns a string constant, so it's equivalent to initializing the property with that constant value.)